Covering of $\Bbb RP^2\times\Bbb RP^2$ that corresponds to $\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$
The question I got was:

Find all the coverings of $\Bbb RP^2\times\Bbb RP^2$ (upto isomorphism).

Now, I know that $\pi_1(\Bbb RP^2\times\Bbb RP^2)=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, which has five subgroups. There is one covering space corresponding to each of these, by standard results. Now, I can describe four of these explicitly (noting that $q\colon S^2\to\Bbb RP^2$ is a cover),

For $0$, just take $S^2\times S^2$ with the map $q\times q$.

For $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, just take $\Bbb RP^2\times\Bbb RP^2$ with the map $\operatorname{id}\times\operatorname{id}$.

For $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\oplus0$, just take $\Bbb RP^2\times S^2$ with the map $\operatorname{id}\times q$.

For $0\oplus\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, just take $S^2\times\Bbb RP^2$ with the map $q\times\operatorname{id}$.


But I don't know how to explicitly describe the map that corresponds to the subgroup $\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$. I feel it has to be $S^2\times\Bbb RP^2$, but I could not come up with a map.

It is perhaps worthwhile to better understand the correspondence between subgroups of $\pi_1(X)$ and covering spaces of $X$.  We have the universal cover $\tilde{X}\to X$, and the collection of deck transformations of this cover is isomorphic to the fundamental group. Given a subgroup $H\subset G$  of the group of deck transformation of a cover $\tilde{X}\to X$, we get a new covering map by defining an equivalence relation on $\tilde{X}$ by $x\sim h(x)$ for $h\in H$.  The corresponding quotient space of $\tilde{X}$ will be a covering of $X$.
So we wish to take $S^2\times S^2$ and quotient by the relation $(a,b)\sim (-a,-b)$ where we are viewing $S^2$ as the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^3$, so that $-a$ is the antipodal point to $a$.  I don't have a great intuition for 4 dimensional non-orientable manifolds, so I cannot say exactly what this looks like or if it is homeomorphic to a simpler space, but it is straight forward to say what the covering map is from this description, and describing the covering map might not be as clear if we have to compose with that homeomorphism.

I don't know what a deck transformation is. Could you explain it in easier words?

@ultralegend5385 A deck transformation is a symmetry of a covering space.  Given a covering map $\pi:Y\to X$, a deck transformation is a homeomorphism $\sigma:Y\to Y$ such that $\pi\sigma=\pi$.  For example, we have a covering map $\mathbb R\to S^1$ given by $x\mapsto e^{2\pi i x}$, where we view $S^1$ as the unit circle in $\mathbb C$.  The map $x\mapsto x+1$ is then a deck transformation, because $e^{2\pi i x}=e^{2\pi i (x+1)}$ for all $x$.  It is a standard result in covering theory that the fundamental group of a space acts on its universal cover by deck transformations.

Thanks, apparently we learnt deck transformations under the name "covering space automorphisms". Can you point to some reference / give some hints for how the cover in first paragraph corresponds to $H$?

@ultralegend5385 it should be in literally any resource that talks about fundamental groups and covering space theory. You were the one who initially said there was a correspondence between subgroups and covering spaces: what was the correspondence you had in mind? Was the proof you had in your book entirely non-constructive?

The way I know it is, given a subgroup $H$ of $\pi_1(B,b_0)$, let $P$ be the set of all paths starting from $b_0$ in $B$, and then define $\alpha\sim\beta$ if $[\alpha\ast\overline{\beta}]\in H$. Then, let $E=P/\sim$ and give it the quotient topology inherited from the compact-open topology on $P$. Then, we show that the map $p\colon E\to B$ sending $\alpha\mapsto\alpha(1)$ is a covering map.

@ultralegend5385 This is essentially equivalent.  What you've done in terms of paths essentially defines how $\pi_1(B,b_0)$ acts on $\tilde{B}$ (since $\tilde{B}$ can be constructed this way taking $H={e}$, and compositions of quotient maps are quotient maps).  We are simply breaking our thinking into abstractions where we have a group acting on a simply connected covering space and looking at the quotients of the group action.

Thanks for the reply, I will think more about it, and ask a new question if needed, since this is far from the actual problem. I will accept this answer.

When I thought about this problem, it occurred to me that one can think of your covering space as the nontrivial $S^2$ bundle over $\mathbb RP^2$, meaning that when you go once around a nontrivial loop in the base space $\mathbb RP^2$, the monodromy on the $S^2$ fiber is the antipodal map. The deck action by $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ takes each fiber to itself by the antipodal map on that fiber, and the quotient of that action is $\mathbb RP^2 \times \mathbb RP^2$.
Here is a distillation of these thoughts down to more elementary terms.
Consider the composition
$$g : S^2 \times S^2 \xrightarrow{g_1}S^2 \xrightarrow{g_2} \mathbb RP^2
$$
where $g_1(p,q)=p$ which is the projection of $S^2 \times S^2$ onto its first factor, and $g_2$ is the standard covering map. This composition commutes with the "deck transformation" action of $(1,1)$, which means precisely this:

The group element $(1,1)$ corresponds to the homeomorphism of $S^2 \times S^2$ that takes $(p,q)$ to $(-p,-q)$.
$g(p,q)=g(-p,-q)$.

The map $g$ therefore induces a well-defined map $\hat g : Q \to \mathbb RP^2$ on the quotient space
$$Q = (S^2 \times S^2) \bigm/ \bigl((p,q) \sim (-p,-q)\bigr)
$$
One obtains another map $\hat h : Q \mapsto \mathbb RP^2$ by doing the same thing using the projection of $S^2 \times S^2$ onto its second factor: define
$$h : S^2 \times S^2 \xrightarrow{h_1} S^2 \xrightarrow{h_2} \mathbb RP^2
$$
where $h_1(p,q) \mapsto q$ and $h_2=g_2$ is, again, the standard covering map. This induces the function $\hat h : Q \to \mathbb RP^2$.
Your desired covering map is the function $(\hat g,\hat h) : Q \to \mathbb RP^2 \times \mathbb RP^2$ taking each $X \in Q$ to $(\hat g(X),\hat h(X))$. Your desired covering space is $Q$, which you should be able to prove using the same "standard results".

I don't know what a deck transformation or a fiber bundle is. Could you explain it in easier words?

Deck transformations are an integral part of covering space theory. Whatever book you read from about covering maps, deck transformations are probably on the next page or soon thereafter; see, for example, Munkres Topology.

For this particular problem, all you need to know is an exact description of the deck action by each of the elements of $\mathbb Z/2 \oplus \mathbb Z/2$ on the covering space $S^2 \times S^2$: $(1,0)$ takes $(p,q)$ to $(-p,q)$; $(1,1)$ takes $(p,q)$ to $(-p,-q)$; $(0,1)$ takes $(p,q)$ to $(p,-q)$; $(0,0)$ acts as the identity.

Fiber bundles are a generalization of covering space theory. For this problem, while it gives a helpful background to let one discover what the covering space actually is, all you really have to do is to understand the construction in my second paragraph.

I rewrote my second paragraph to try to put it in easier words (at the expense of obscuring how one can actually discover the solution to this problem, which I did by using deck transformations and fiber bundles).

One last thing: you used the word "standard results" in place of any proof that there is a covering space corresponding to each subgroup. So whatever "standard results" means to you, you should be able to prove that the space $Q$ that I described is the covering space corresponding to the $(1,1)$ subgroup.  One thing to keep in mind as you progress through covering space theory is that "standard results" about covering maps usually includes deck transformation theory.

Thanks, apparently we learnt deck transformations under the name "covering space automorphisms". I still am unable to see why $Q$ corresponds to $(1,1)$. Could you give some hints?

I could do that except you gave no details of your understanding of this correspondence. Perhaps you could update your post to add details of what "standard results" you applied to justify the correspondence for the covering spaces listed in your post. Then I would know where to start (rather than writing out a description of the correspondence only to find out you already know that).
